# SQL select statement to distinct entries

Tags: sql

My dbase table contanins the below fields :

**gameid, subscriberid, contestsno, mobileno, timestamp, hashcode, score, langType, actualscore, timetaken, vcnumber, subid;**

I need to select unique (subid) 40 entries  whose score is highest and less time taken.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your flavour of SQL:

```
select * from <tablename> order by score, timetaken desc limit 40;
```

or:

```
select top 40 * from <tablename> order by score, timetaken desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct actualscore,subid,timetaken,timestamp FROM mytable where score !='invalid score' and actualscore !='0' order by actualscore desc,timetaken asc ,timestamp asc;
```

The above query gives me result set which contains multiple subids . i want to eliminate duplicate with satisfying my above given condition in query

Comment: Don't add new information as answers. Edit your question